# Is this an accurate way of reversing a string in python?

Tags: python

I just want to know if this is a good way or not.

```
Input_str = "random Str"
Output_str = ""

for i in range(len(Input_str)+1):
      if i == 0: continue
      Output_str += Input_str[-i]

print(Output_str)
```

Comment: Input_str[::-1]

Comment: if you want to test your working code you can ask here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

To quickly reverse a string use the following code:

```
string = "string"
string[::-1]
>>> gnirts
```

It takes the entire string and iterates reversely over it .

Answer (score 1):

There is a better and more pythonistic way to do this (although your code works just fine).

```py
output_str = input_str[::-1]
```

This will pretty much do exactly what your code does - it will iterate from the end of the string towards the front and save that reversed string into the new variable.

You can read more about this syntax called string slicing [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://realpython.com/lessons/string-slicing/&ved=2ahUKEwiCifnmha35AhV38LsIHXtJBf4QFnoECAYQBQ&usg=AOvVaw2DBgh7DFSRhAFVlxugrH4u).